# How Flutter uses its own DartVM for native apps

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I've read that Dart uses its own DartVM.
Thus Flutter can use JIT (for things like hot-reload) while developing your app and AOT to build the latter into a "native" app (*.apk/.ipa*).

According to the [docs](https://flutter.io/faq/#technology) for both platforms (*Android/iOS*):

> ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled into a native, ARM library

But how does Flutter use its own DartVM, for example, on Android, if the app already runs via Dalvik/ART? And does the VM is built into our *.apk* so it can be delivered to a real Android device?

If DartVM isn't used for the end-builds then what about the GC stuff? Flutter tends to create a lot of short-lived objects which is fine for DartVM's [Generational GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29) but isn't so good for the ART's one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Flutter engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine) uses the Dart VM in two distinct modes:

- Running in debug mode at development time, the `flutter run` command watches the host filesystem for changes to Dart source, and when it detects such changes, quickly compiles the Dart source to [kernel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/kernel) (intermediate) format. This is then synced to the engine running on the device via hot-reload, and executed in JIT mode (Android) or interpreted mode (iOS).
- Running in profile or release mode, the Dart source is first compiled to kernel intermediate form, then run through `gen_snapshot`, which emits AOT ARM machine code, which is then linked into the final app. You can find a detailed explanation of [AOT mode operation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-engine-operation-in-AOT-Mode) on our wiki.

Note that there's a thin set of platform bindings for Android written in Java that interface with the engine via JNI, but the core of Flutter's engine is written in C++ and built with the NDK, as such those bits aren't relying on Dalvik/ART.